# Empurrar elemento de um array para outro array

Tags: javascript

função que aceita um parâmetro e é uma matriz numérica
e vai atravessar o array e se o elemento for par vai empurrar para o um array "par" e se for impar vai empurrar para o array "impar"

Eu tentei fazer dessa forma abaixo mas nada funcionou. Qual seria a solução correta?

```
 function PickIt(array) {
  var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  var par = [];
  var impar = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
      return par.push(array[i]);
    } else {
      return impar.push(array[i]);

    }
  }
}
PickIt();
```

Comment: Estou surpreso que ninguém sugeriu usar o forEach. Fica tão mais simples e legível.

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 6):

No primeiro return (no número 1 que é ímpar), irá sair da função retornando apenas o número 1. O `return` finaliza a função retornando o valor que foi encontrado. Por isso tem que colocá-lo após ter processado o que queria.

Você deve colocar um return no final da função (após o laço `for`) retornando as duas arrays, por exemplo, em forma de objeto, cada qual com seu nome.

Me parece que você quer passar a array como parâmetro, então a array deveria estar fora da função, e não dentro dela.

Para deixar seu código mais simples, você pode usar `.filter` com um operador ternário:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function PickIt(array) {
  var par = [], impar = [];
  array.filter(i=>{ (i % 2 === 0 ? par : impar).push(i); });
  return {par, impar};
}

console.log(PickIt(array));       // a função retorna as duas arrays no mesmo objeto
console.log(PickIt(array).par);   // retorna apenas a array par[]
console.log(PickIt(array).impar); // retorna apenas a array impar[]
```

O objeto `PickIt(array).par` é uma array com os números pares e o `PickIt(array).impar` com os números ímpares.

Comment: Vc cria uma função com oum parametro (array) e na chamada da função vc não passa esse parametro !

Comment: Não tinha nem notado rs

Comment: Eu pensei !! gostei da sua solução agora  +1 :)

Comment: Obg cara! A sua tb é boa. Valeu!

Answer (score 6):

Vc pode definir suas variaveis fora da função se vc quiser usar elas depois.
Vc não precisa colocar como argumento array que já e definido.

```js
     var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
     var par = [];
     var impar = [];
    
     function PickIt() {
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
          par.push(array[i]);
        } else {
          impar.push(array[i]);
  
        }
      }
    }
    PickIt();
    console.log('par => ' + par);
    console.log('impar => ' + impar);
```

Answer (score 6):

Acredito que existe algumas soluções acabei implementando em cima do seu próprio código que estava quase certo, e preferi passar o `array` por parâmetro e ter o resultado logo apos a execução, exemplo?

```js
function PickIt(array) 
{  
  var result = [];
 
  result[`par`] = [];
  result[`impar`] = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
      result[`par`].push(array[i]);
    } else {
      result[`impar`].push(array[i]);
    }
  } 
  return result;
}
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var result = PickIt(array);
console.log(result[`par`]);
console.log(result[`impar`]);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Usando Filter

Embora o filter faça com que a execução passe duas vezes pelo array, o código fica mais simples.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function PickIt(arr) {
  return { 
    par: arr.filter(x => (x % 2 == 0)),
    impar: arr.filter(x => (x % 2 != 0))
  };
}

var result = PickIt(array);
console.log(result.par);
console.log(result.impar);
```

Answer (score 1):

como nosso amigo Máttheus disse, com uso de **forEach** fica mais legível.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 var par = [];
 var impar = [];

 function PickIt() {
  array.forEach(function(v,i) {   // v -> valor do array, i -> indice do array
    
    if(v % 2 == 0){               // Verifica os valores
      par.push(v);
    } else {
      impar.push(v);
    }
  })
}
PickIt();
console.log(par);
console.log(impar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Me atendo à sua pergunta sobre qual solução seria correta e sem mexer muito no seu código, a sua está quase correta, você apenas não pediu pra exibir o resultado na tela além de ter usado equivocadamente o 'return'.

Tirei o 'return' para que na chamada da função, após o primeiro 'return', a execução não saia da sub-rotina atual e retorne para o ponto em que foi chamada parando a execução do 'for'. Depois de finalizado o 'for', pedi pra imprimir os arrays par e impar, usando o 'console.log'. Através deste, posso então visualizar o resultado na ferramenta do desenvolvedor do navegador.

```
function PickIt(array) {
  var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  var par = [];
  var impar = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] % 2 === 0) {
       par.push(array[i]);
    } else {
       impar.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(par);
  console.log(impar);
}
PickIt();
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando a sintaxe [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) introduzida no `ES6` você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```js
const PickIt = elementos => {
  let pares = [];
  let impares = [];

  // Percorre cada item
  for (let elemento of elementos) {
    // Define a referência do array válido para este elemento
    let alvo = elemento % 2 === 0 ? pares: impares;

    // Adiciona o elemento
    alvo.push(elemento);
  }

  // Retorna o resultado nomeado
  return { pares, impares };
}

// Aqui vai a utilização
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let { pares, impares } = PickIt(array);

console.log('pares =>', pares.join(', '));
console.log('impares =>', impares.join(', '));
```

Lembrando que a solução acima não é compatível com todos os navegadores e versões

---

> [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
>
> O loop `for...of` percorre objetos iterativos (incluindo `Array`, `Map`, `Set`, o objeto `arguments` e assim por diante), chamando uma função personalizada com instruções a serem executadas para o valor de cada objeto distinto.